# AngularJS - change scope of HTML element to new scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and doing some freaking experiments to clear by concepts about `scope`, `directives` and `dom`.

*AIM* : Change the scope of HTML element `<div id="grocery">` to newly created child scope'

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="eggly" ng-controller="rootCtrl">
  <body>
     <div id="grocery">  
        {{box}}
     </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

**rootCtrl**

```
eggly.controller('rootCtrl',function($scope,$timeout,$compile){

   $scope.box = "lunchbox";  --> first assign box = lunchbox
   $timeout(function(){

      //delete $scope;
      var newScope = $scope.$new();  --> create a new scope
      newScope.box = "dinnerbox";  ---> Assign new value
      $compile($('#grocery'))(newScope);  --> compile div with new scope
      //newScope.$apply();  --> I think $timeout already do $apply so commented out 

  },1000);

});
```

My issue is:

1. If I do not create `new scope` and do not `$compile` in `$timeout` function then my view is updated with `dinnerbox` as I am expecting
2. If I create `new scope` and `$compile` in `$timeout` function then my view shows me old value i.e `lunchbox` however chrome console show me `angular.element($0).scope().box` shows me `dinnerbox` in scope (after $timeout execution).

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: None of this belongs in controller in the first place. Also you don't use `$compile` on a jQuery object.  What you are trying to do is create a poor man's directive and should use a real angular directive for this.

Comment: @charlietfl : Apart from what you have commented, only thing I am expecting from you, do you know why it is not working ?? Thanks

Comment: @charlietfl : with $compile either you can use angular.element of jquery object .. AFAIK

Comment: Already explained that you should use directive. . Internally `$apply()` will still use original scope. You should also completely remove jQuery from project if you are just learning angular

Answer (score 0):

When `$compile` is being called, `#grocery` contents are `lunchbox` and not `{{ box }}`. At this moment `ng-controller` directive was already linked and binding information is not available as plain HTML.

This shortcoming can be overcome by using directive substitute to `{{ }}` binding:

```
<div id="grocery"><span ng-bind="box"></span></div>
```

Comment: This is one of the numerous things that may be referred with 'don't use jQuery with Angular' statement. The problem is not jQuery but the level of proficiency it requires to break Angular recommended workflow but make it work smoothly. At this level the developer usually realizes that 98% of familiar jQuery use cases are antipatterns in Angular.